iOS18 onTapGesture stopped working with Menu
Issue:
After updating to Swift 6 and iOS 18, the Menu component's interaction is not behaving as expected. The onTapGesture and primaryAction don't work correctly to trigger the desired action when the user taps on the menu.
Code Examples:
Using onTapGesture with Menu (not working):
Menu {
    Button(action: {}) {
        Label("Add to Reading List", systemImage: "eyeglasses")
    }
    Button(action: {}) {
        Label("Add Bookmarks for All Tabs", systemImage: "book")
    }
    Button(action: {}) {
        Label("Show All Bookmarks", systemImage: "books.vertical")
    }
} label: {
    Label("Add Bookmark", systemImage: "book")
} onTapGesture: {
    print("Print on tap gesture")
}

Using primaryAction (Menu not appears but action is triggered on tap):
Menu {
    Button(action: {}) {
        Label("Add to Reading List", systemImage: "eyeglasses")
    }
    Button(action: {}) {
        Label("Add Bookmarks for All Tabs", systemImage: "book")
    }
    Button(action: {}) {
        Label("Show All Bookmarks", systemImage: "books.vertical")
    }
} label: {
    Label("Add Bookmark", systemImage: "book")
} primaryAction: {
    print("Primary action triggered")
}

Trying to overlay a tap area (no effect):
ZStack {
    Menu {
        Button(action: {}) {
            Label("Add to Reading List", systemImage: "eyeglasses")
        }
        Button(action: {}) {
            Label("Add Bookmarks for All Tabs", systemImage: "book")
        }
        Button(action: {}) {
            Label("Show All Bookmarks", systemImage: "books.vertical")
        }
    } label: {
        Label("Add Bookmark", systemImage: "book")
    }
    Color.clear
        .contentShape(Rectangle())
        .onTapGesture {
            print("Tap gesture recognized")
        }
}

Please help.
How to start action when user is clicking on menu?

I’m surprised it worked in the first place. For Context Menu you have to tap into UIKit to do this reliably.

It's working on every previous system but not on 18...

I have a similar problem. I'm still looking for a fix (the comment above didn't help). Temporary solution: Compile the project with Xcode 15.4 makes everything work as before.

I have face the same issue after iOS 18 update came in the market. my project in swiftUI and there is I used onTap gesture recognition modifier many time on a Textflied, Image and text.
These all are have problem while tap on it many time it's stuck and some time this is working fine. so I figure it out the solution of this instead of using onTapGesture modifier I use highPriorityGesture it's working very well for me try this I hope it will resolve your problem.
.highPriorityGesture(
    TapGesture().onEnded {
        print("Tap gesture recognized")
    }
)

